# Задача про обход конем доски.

Tags: c, рекурсия

Добрый день!
Классическая задача на рекурсивный перебор с возвратом про обход конем всей шахматной доски... Задача вроде как не сложная, да и как делать понятно. Пытаюсь построить ее на Си и выводит пустую доску... Помогите, пожалуйста, найти косяк, меня уже глючит.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A[8][8];
const int dx[8]={2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2};
const int dy[8]={1,2,2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1};
int s;

void rek (int x, int y, bool OK);

int main (void)
{
    int x, y;
    s=2;
    for (x=0; x<8; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<8; y++)
        {
            A[x][y]=0;
        }
    } 
    A[0][0]=1;

    rek(0,0, false);

    for (x=0; x<8; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<8; y++)
        {
            printf("%d   ", A[x][y]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    } 
}

void rek (int x, int y, bool OK)
{
    int x1, y1;
    bool OK1;
    int c;
    c=0;
    do
    {
        OK1=false;
        x1=x+dx[c];
        y1=y+dy[c];
        c++;
        if (  (x1>=0)&&(y1>=0)&&(x1<=7)&&(y1<=7)&&(A[x1][y1]==0)  ) 
        {
            A[x1][y1]=s;
            if (s<64)
            {
                s++;
                rek (x1, y1, OK1);
                if (OK1==false)
                {
                    A[x1][y1]=0;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                OK1=true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (  (OK1==true)||(c==8)  );
    OK=OK1;
}
```

Comment: fori1ton, спасибо большое за подробный ответ!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы слишком усложнили функцию `rek`.   
Во-первых, хранить номер шага в глобальной переменной в этой задаче не слишком красиво: его лучше передавать в виде параметра в рекурсию.  
Во-вторых, проверка `s < 64` совершенно излишня: после 63 ходов коня на поле не останется ни одной непосещённой клетки (с A[x][y] == 0), так что рекурсия завершится сама собой.  
Ну и в-третьих, не совсем понятен смысл вычисления и тем более передачи в качестве параметра в рекурсию параметра `OK`. Его как раз можно было вынести в глобальную область.    Подытоживая всё вышесказанное, функцию `rek` можно (и нужно) переписать следующим образом:

```
void rek (int x, int y, int step)
{
    A[x][y] = step;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)          
    {
        int x1 = x + dx[i];
        int y1 = y + dy[i];

        if ((x1 >= 0) && (y1 >= 0) && (x1 < 8) && (y1 < 8) && (A[x1][y1] == 0))
        {
            rek(x1, y1, step + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

А насчёт того, что в вашем варианте весь массив забивался нулями, то это потому, что вы при первом вызове передавали в качестве параметра `OK` false, а в функции `rek` он устанавливался в true только когда количество шагов достигало 64. Пока `OK == false`, вы присваиваете элементу массива значение 0. Когда же s достигает значения 64, то переменная `OK` устанавливается в true, и происходит выход из рекурсии. Таким образом массив остаётся в том же состоянии, что и до вызова функции.